# Can't filter custom metrics in google cloud monitoring with tags

Tags: go, gcloud, opencensus

I registered stats with opencensus and attached tags thanks to a StackDriver exporter:

```
ctx, err = tag.New(ctx, tag.Upsert(key, val))
stats.Record(ctx, []stats.Measurement{csqAverage.M(m)}...)
```

In the metric explorer, I can see the metrics, but I can't see or filter with the associated tag. When I retrieve the resources thanks to the REST API, I don't see tags at all, and this kind of property is not mentionened in the documentation describing a metric. However, the gcloud documentation indicates that opencensus tag can be exported to filter the metrics.

Comment: It's been some time since I used OpenCensus but IIRC tags map to labels (!) in Cloud Monitoring (formerly Stackdriver)

Comment: See: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/open-census#opencensus-vocabulary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TagKeys must be declared in the registered view.